# iOS delegate naming conventions - should, will, did

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am looking into naming conventions for iOS controls delegates. I am familiar with the [should, will, did pattern for delegate methods](http://mattgemmell.com/2012/05/24/api-design/). I can see this naming convention used extensively by the Apple APIs. My question is, are there any delegates supplied by apple that have should, will, did methods for a single action? e.g. for row selection:

```
shouldSelectRow
willSelectRow
didSelectRow
```

I have not found a delegate that defines all three. My feeling is that 'will' methods are often used in place of should, i.e. they can return a value in order to cancel the action.

Are there any counter-examples?

Comment: I think you got it flipped - "should" should return a boolean that tells the sender to proceed or not. Will it telling you it WILL happen and there's noting you can do about. Did lets you take actions after its happened. My $0.02

Comment: I combine the use of will and should, so will is called, but with the option to return NO if you don't want the change to go ahead. The should method makes no sense to me. It's just extra overhead.

Comment: @DavidH that was my initial understanding, however, the `UITableViewDelegate` method `tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath` can return a value that cancels selection. In other words, it performs the 'should' responsibility.

Comment: Hah - right - well that's why I said "my $0.02". Why not post this on the ObjectiveC listserv? Then you'll get Greg Parker to opine on this :-)

Answer (score 1):

Should methods always return a BOOL value, and tell you the current behavior of an object (But they are never called automatically). Will methods are delegate methods that get called when an event is about to happen, like

```
-(void)applicationWillResignActive...
```

and "did" methods are also delegate methods that get called after the event took place, like appplicationDidFinishLaunching...

Comment: I mean should methods are always called to "ask" you if something should happen or not. For example, this function
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string;
lets you decide if the characters in that range should be changed or not. The code in the function will only make that decision and return YES or NO.